# How to use indexOf in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

All the examples I see of using the IndexOf() method in KnockoutJS are of basic string types. What I want to know is how to return the index of a array  that is an object, based on one of the object variables.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

An observableArray exposes a method called `indexOf`, which is a wrapper to `ko.utils.arrayIndexOf` that simply loops through the array looking for the item that you pass to it.

So, if you have the item you can do:

```
var viewModel = {
   items: ko.observableArray([{id: 1, name: "one"}, {id:2, name: "two"}])
};

var item = viewModel.items()[1];

console.log(viewModel.items.indexOf(item)); //equals 1
```

If you just have something like a key, then KO does have a utility function called `ko.utils.arrayFirst` that just loops through the array trying to match the condition that you pass to it.  However, it returns the item and not the index of it.  It would be slightly inefficient to get the object and then call indexOf on it, as you would make two passes through the array.

You could just write a loop yourself looking for the right item or write a generic function based on ko.utils.arrayFirst that would look like:

```
function arrayFirstIndexOf(array, predicate, predicateOwner) {
    for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (predicate.call(predicateOwner, array[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now, you can pass an array, a condition, and you will be returned the index of the first item that matches.

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([{
        id: 1,
        name: "one"},
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "two"}])
};

var id = 2;

console.log(arrayFirstIndexOf(viewModel.items(), function(item) {
   return item.id === id;    
})); //returns 1
```

Comment: In your example shouldn't return item.id === id;  be return item.id() === id;?  I'm trying do something very close to this and had to had the ().

Comment: Just depends if `id` is observable or not. In this case it is not, but sounds like for you it is.