# ko.utils.arrayFirst = function (array, predicate, predicateOwner) { /* .. */ }

Tags: knockout.js

what does predicateOwner mean , i couldn't find an answer ?!

like this:

[How to use indexOf in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926155/how-to-use-indexof-in-knockoutjs)

or that

https://gist.github.com/hyle/8840a083bcd1325a59ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last parameter of *arrayFirst* - is context that would be assigned to predicate's scope:

```js
var array = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);
var context = "Hello";
var result = ko.utils.arrayFirst(array(), function(item) {
  // 'this' is equal 'context'
  console.log(this);
  return item === 2;
}, context);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```